# How to get multiple values of a value in variant array in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So pretty much I want to this part of the code to pull up products associated with student ID  that the customer inputs. so the action isn't just pulling up the specific products on that page.

```
  <form autocomplete="off" action="https://xbooks5407.com/collections/2019-20-school-year/" method="get">
<div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
  <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myStudent_id" placeholder="Student ID Number">
</div>
<input type="submit" class="get started" value="Get Started">
```

Also the student id array is in the javascript script. Those Ids show up under the search bar which is great, but when actually clicking it won't pull up specific products on the `action=` landing page.

Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. As it is, it's impossible to eyeball-debug your code

Comment: This might be a very easy question to answer if it were more clear. (Maybe you're looking for something like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp?)... 
Basically, what does the structure of an item in your JavaScript Array look like? -- I'm guessing you want to loop through the Array and modify the corresponding HTML Element where the item gets shown, setting the Element's `style` Attribute's `display` Property (like `element.style.display = "none"` or `element.style.display = ""`) based on whether the item's `studentID` property matches some specific value...